# How to convert Normal/cdf() computation that was originally written using sympy.statistics to use sympy.stats?

Tags: python, sympy

I haven't kept up with the changes in SymPy. I was looking at the following Black Scholes formula at: https://aaronschlegel.me/black-scholes-formula-python.html. It seems there was some refactoring that was done in SymPy so this no longer works. How would I change the following so it works again:

```
import sympy as sy
import sympy.statistics as systats

def euro_put_sym(S, K, T, r, sigma):        
    #S: spot price
    #K: strike price
    #T: time to maturity
    #r: interest rate
    #sigma: volatility of underlying asset

    N = systats.Normal(0.0, 1.0)

    d1 = (sy.ln(S / K) + (r + 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * T) / (sigma * sy.sqrt(T))
    d2 = (sy.ln(S / K) + (r - 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * T) / (sigma * sy.sqrt(T))

    put = (K * sy.exp(-r * T) * N.cdf(-d2) - S * N.cdf(-d1))

    return put
```

> The errors I get are:
>
> No name 'statistics' in module 'sympy'
>
> Unable to import 'sympy.statistics'

In particular, how would the `Normal` and `cdf` be done now?

Comment: what does "no longer works" mean? do you get an error or just bad results?

Comment: I get an error. The statistics package was replaced by stats with different methods

Comment: I recommended including that error in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statistics module in Sympy is named `stats`.
 Also, `Normal` takes 3 parameters. A simple usage example is shown below:

```
>>> from sympy import symbols

>>> from sympy.stats import Normal, density, cdf

>>> x, mu, sigma = symbols("x mu sigma")

>>> N = Normal("N", mu, sigma)

>>> density(N)(x)

sqrt(2)*exp(-(-mu + x)**2/(2*sigma**2))/(2*sqrt(pi)*sigma)

>>> cdf(N)(x)

erf(sqrt(2)*(-mu + x)/(2*sigma))/2 + 1/2
```

For further reference, see [Sympy Stats docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/stats.html) and [Normal Distribution docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/stats.html#sympy.stats.Normal).

Now for your case, let me explain what you should be doing.

```
import sympy as sy
import sympy.stats as systats

def euro_put_sym(S, K, T, r, sigma):        
    #S: spot price
    #K: strike price
    #T: time to maturity
    #r: interest rate
    #sigma: volatility of underlying asset

    N = systats.Normal('N', 0.0, 1.0)

    d1 = (sy.ln(S / K) + (r + 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * T) / (sigma * sy.sqrt(T))
    d2 = (sy.ln(S / K) + (r - 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * T) / (sigma * sy.sqrt(T))

    put = (K * sy.exp(-r * T) * systats.cdf(N)(-d2) - S * systats.cdf(N)(-d1))

    return put
```

Now,

```
S, K, T, r, sigma = sy.symbols("S K T r sigma")
sy.pprint(euro_put_sym(S, K, T, r, sigma), use_unicode=False)
```

gives output as

```
  /       /      ___ /  /             2\      /S\\\\           /       /      
  |       |0.5*\/ 2 *|T*\r - 0.5*sigma / + log|-||||           |       |0.5*\/
  |       |          \                        \K//||           |       |      
  |    erf|---------------------------------------||           |    erf|------
  |       |                ___                    ||           |       |      
  |1      \              \/ T *sigma              /|  -T*r     |1      \      
K*|- - --------------------------------------------|*e     - S*|- - ----------
  \2                        2                      /           \2             

___ /  /             2\      /S\\\\
 2 *|T*\r + 0.5*sigma / + log|-||||
    \                        \K//||
---------------------------------||
          ___                    ||
        \/ T *sigma              /|
----------------------------------|
           2                      /
```

Is this the expected output?

I tested it through the example in the link you have provided and the results are matching.

```
>>> euro_put_sym(50, 100, 1, 0.05, 0.25)
-25*erf(1.22379436111989*sqrt(2)) + 22.5614712250357 + 47.5614712250357*erf(1.34879436111989*sqrt(2))
```

Comment: better explanation than my example

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the correct conversion from the old statistics package to the new one. What do you guys think?

```
import sympy as sy
import sympy.stats as systats

def euro_put_sym(S, K, T, r, sigma):        
    #S: spot price
    #K: strike price
    #T: time to maturity
    #r: interest rate
    #sigma: volatility of underlying asset

    N = systats.Normal('x', 0.0, 1.0)

    d1 = (sy.ln(S / K) + (r + 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * T) / (sigma * sy.sqrt(T))
    d2 = (sy.ln(S / K) + (r - 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * T) / (sigma * sy.sqrt(T))

    put = (K * sy.exp(-r * T) * systats.cdf(N)(-d2) - S * systats.cdf(N)(-d1))

    return put
```